# Handle NSItemProvider data types in Share Extension (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, nsdata

I have an issue with **Share Extension** programming in **Swift** (3). 
My main problem is with the handling of the `data` type of a *NSItemProvider*.
Here's the issue: depending on the App that I launch my Extension from, I get a different type of data. For example:
I tell the application:

```
let IMAGE_TYPE = kUTTypeImage as String
if attachment.hasItemConformingToTypeIdentifier(IMAGE_TYPE){
     attachment.loadItem(forTypeIdentifier: IMAGE_TYPE, options: nil){ data, error in
     ...
}
```

(Note: *attachment* is of type *NSItemProvider*)
When executed from the Photos App, `data` is a URL so I create a UIImage from that and continue with that.
The problem is, that for some applications `data` already is a UIImage and I can't find how to do the case differentiation. 
Best would probably be to check the data type of the `data` object but it's not trivial to me at least.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As far as I tested, in some cases, you will have a `Data` in `data`. So, you may need to write something like this if you do not want to write an Objective-C wrapper for this method:

```
if attachment.hasItemConformingToTypeIdentifier(IMAGE_TYPE) {
    attachment.loadItem(forTypeIdentifier: IMAGE_TYPE, options: nil) { data, error in
        let myImage: UIImage?
        switch data {
        case let image as UIImage:
            myImage = image
        case let data as Data:
            myImage = UIImage(data: data)
        case let url as URL:
            myImage = UIImage(contentsOfFile: url.path)
        default:
            //There may be other cases...
            print("Unexpected data:", type(of: data))
            myImage = nil
        }
        //...
    }
}
```

(Not tested, you may need to fix some parts.)

---

In Objective-C, you can pass an Objective-C block taking `(UIImage *item, NSError *error)` to the `completionHandler` of `loadItemForTypeIdentifier:options:completionHandler:`. In such case, the item provider tries to convert all sorts image data into `UIImage`.

[NSItemProviderCompletionHandler](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsitemprovidercompletionhandler?language=objc)

> ## Discussion
>
> ...
>
> #### item
>
> The item to be loaded. When specifying your block, set the type of this parameter to the specific data type you want. ... The item provider attempts to coerce the data to the class you specify.

So, if you do not mind writing some Objective-C wrapper, you can write something like this:

NSItemProvider+Swift.h:

```
@import UIKit;

typedef void (^NSItemProviderCompletionHandlerForImage)(UIImage *image, NSError *error);

@interface NSItemProvider(Swift)
- (void)loadImageForTypeIdentifier:(NSString *)typeIdentifier
                          options:(NSDictionary *)options
                completionHandler:(NSItemProviderCompletionHandlerForImage)completionHandler;
@end
```

NSItemProvider+Swift.m:

```
#import "NSItemProvider+Swift.h"

@implementation  NSItemProvider(Swift)

- (void)loadImageForTypeIdentifier:(NSString *)typeIdentifier
                           options:(NSDictionary *)options
                 completionHandler:(NSItemProviderCompletionHandlerForImage)completionHandler {
    [self loadItemForTypeIdentifier:typeIdentifier
                            options:options
                  completionHandler:completionHandler];
}

@end
```

{YourProject}-Bridging-Header.h:

```
#import "NSItemProvider+Swift.h"
```

And use it from Swift as:

```
    if attachment.hasItemConformingToTypeIdentifier(IMAGE_TYPE) {
        attachment.loadImage(forTypeIdentifier: IMAGE_TYPE, options: nil) { myImage, error in
            //...
        }
    }
```

In my opinion, Apple should provide this sort of type-safe extension of `NSItemProvider`, you can write a feature request using Apple's [Bug Reporter](http://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/).

Comment: Thank you very much, that was perfect!

Comment: Tried everything else, this is the one that worked.

Answer (score 6):

There's a new API that is used in examples, canLoadObject and loadObject

```
if (itemProvider.canLoadObject(ofClass: UIImage.self)) {
            itemProvider.loadObject(ofClass: UIImage.self, completionHandler: {
                (data, error) in
                print("==== adding image \(image) as note, error=\(error)")
})
```

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/drag_and_drop/data_delivery_with_drag_and_drop

Comment: Is tried this because it seems made for Swift and it seems that the class parameter will solve the problem but sadly it doesn't at all. I think there's a bug in the bridge between Swift (whatever we use the old or new function) and the `Résoudre l'erreur _EXSinkLoadOperator` . So the only working solution is to directly use the Objective-C function (indeed it works and avoid the error in console logs).

Comment: I was able to load a UIImage to display a preview in my share extension using `loadObject`. It seems there is a bridging bug in `loadPreviewImage` and `loadDataRepresentation`.